# visualizing repeated measure longitudinal discrete outcome

Tags: categorical-data, data-visualization, repeated-measures

This may be a repeat of some questions asked here before, I apologize in advance if thats the case. At at rate, here's my question.

I am dealing with a binary outcome, wheezing=Yes or wheezing=No, this outcome wheezing is measured repeatedly for about 40,000 kids. Unevenly evaluated , some kids are evaluated once , some kids are evaluated 163 times, many others in between this range.

My dataset is like this.

```
    Id    Date        Age     Wheezing_Status
    121   1995-11-23  0.11    No
    121   1997-06-20  1.18    No
    121   2001-07-25  3.12    Yes        
    19    1998-12-20  5.16    No
    17    2002-01-14  1.29    No
    17    2003-11-28  2.67    No        
    17    2007-03-28  4.12    Yes
    17    2012-04-23  11.23   No
    .     .           .       . 
    .     .           .       .
    .     .           .       .
    .     .           .       .
    153   2006-04-21   3.18   No        
    153   2011-01-08   7.13   No
    153   2016-08-30  11.25   No
    119   2003-08-02  23.47   Yes
```

The main factor is, once the kid is wheezing=Yes, the kid should be flagged wheezing=Yes during subsequent visits or evaluations.

I have reasons to believe there is some error in the dataset and there may be some cases or some kids who may have been flagged wheezing=No , AFTER, diagnosed with wheezing=Yes. Example : ID 17

How do I either programmatically or visually identify these cases, kids documented as wheezing=No , AFTER, diagnosed with wheezing=Yes ? Especially when there are repeated measure data for 40,000 kids ?

Comment: It will be very hard to *visualize* this. Why wouldn't you just *programmatically* identify such errors?

Comment: @StephanKolassa, I agree with you, I have updated my question accordingly, but I have seen study sponsors requesting a swim lane diagram with a line indicating each subject progression in time and a dot indicating no and red dot indicating Yes.

Answer (score 3):

If you represent the wheezing status with a value that can be ordered (such as a number) whereby `Yes` is represented as the larger number, and order the data by age (or date), then the correct status is the *cumulative maximum* of these values.  The errors occur where there are discrepancies between the recorded value and this cumulative maximum.

For instance, consider a patient whose recorded status values over time were the sequence

```
No, No, Yes, Yes, Yes, No, Yes
```

The cumulative maximum is

```
No, No, Yes, Yes, Yes, Yes, Yes
```

(It is `No` until the first `Yes` appears, after which it is forever `Yes`).  Upon comparing these two sequences term-by-term, you will identify the error in the sixth term.

If you maintain these data in a `data.table` object in `R` (using the `data.table` add-in), this two-step process requires just two lines: one to make sure the data are sorted by age and one to compare the cumulative max to the data:

```R
setorder(X, Age)
invisible(X[, Error := Recorded != cummax(Recorded), keyby=.(ID)])
```

It relies on equating `TRUE` with the number $1$ and `FALSE` with the number $0.$

There are very many ways to plot this.  `ggplot2` will produce something like what you describe:

[image: Figure]

(Click on the image to see a larger version.)  The red dots locate the erroneous values.

This plot was produced by generating a dataset of 623,012 observations for 40,000 subjects.  I created errors in almost 100 cases (at random)  This plot shows all the erroneous data, plus a few randomly chosen subjects without any errors (for comparison).